# ¿Como compruebo que una variable es una cadena?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo determinar si una variable es una cadena o algo más en JavaScript?

Comment: Agrega tu código para que se tenga un mejor ejemplo de lo que deseas Carlos.

Comment: A que te refieres con *algo más*? Tambien has de mostrar lo intentado y los errores o problemas. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede usar [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/prototype) para hacer una única comparación, ya que `typeof` fallará si se trata de un objeto.

Además, como la pregunta dice:

> ¿Cómo puedo determinar si una variable es una cadena o algo más en
>   JavaScript?

Precisamente, con este método podemos saber siempre de qué tipo es el objeto que estamos evaluando.

Consideremos una función `isString` parecida a esta y probémosla con una cadena simple `str` , con un objeto `strObjeto` y con un número `int`:

```js
var strObjeto = new String('String');
var str = "String";
var int= 10;

console.log(isString(strObjeto));
console.log(isString(str));
console.log(isString(int));



function isString(strValor) 
{
  var bolString=false;
  strTipo=Object.prototype.toString.call(strValor);
  console.log("Tipo: "+strTipo);
  if (strTipo==="[object String]")
  {
    bolString=true;
  }
  return bolString;
}
```

---

Resultado en consola:

```
true
Tipo: [object String]
true
Tipo: [object Number]
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar `typeof`, con esto puedes comprobar si un valor es de determinado tipo, por ejemplo:

```
var value = 'Carlos';
if(typeof value === 'string'){
 //es string.
}
```

También `instanceof` para comparar un objeto de tipo `String`  :

```
var value = new String('Carlos');
if(value instanceof String){
 //es string.    
}
```

Usando jQuery:

```
if($.type(myVar) === "string"){
     //es string.   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

con la funcion `typeof`

por ejemplo

```
if(typeof forma == 'string'){}
```

más info
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof